# express command not found in bash after installing it with npm

Tags: bash, node.js, express, npm

just installed new ubuntu vm to test around with node
installed things in this order:

```
node
mongodb-server
npm
express
mongoose
```

now, trying to create a new app i noticed express cannot be used in the shell.
`express -v`  returns
express: command not found

i installed npm like this

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

and i installed express this way

```
npm install express
```

any ideas?

Comment: npm install -g express-generator   ,  and cd myapp && npm install,  http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`npm install express -g`

You need to install it globally.

Npm 1.0 installs modules locally by default. So the bash executable lives in `/node_modules/bin/`. You can add that folder to `PATH` or you can just install `express` globally so that it's picked up by `PATH`

Comment: You can also run scripts through npm by adding a "scripts" object to your package.json, and doing, "$ npm run-script scriptname".  NPM adds the various bin directories in the local package repo to the path before running the script:

Comment: +1 to add the scripts object to package.json and use `npm run-script scriptname` - this keeps your global space clear and allows you to more accurately test your production environment when in dev.

Answer (score 90):

Starting from express 4.00 you also need to install express generator with:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

Only after this will you be able to run express as a command!

For confirmation see: [*ExpressJS.com - Migrating to Express 4*](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#app-gen)

Comment: Finally! This should be accepted as good answer from now on. I even had express in my PATH variable and nothing was working. Thanks @Fazi.

Comment: True, this is the only way

Comment: Do you have any idea why this just wouldn't work for me?  I run sudo npm install -g express-generator and it installs to usr/bin but I cannot use express.  I type "express test" and nothing happens.  It just returns to the next line.

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and was installing node via Homebrew. The problem was being caused by Homebrew.

So I did:

```
brew uninstall node
```

and then installed node using the installer on the [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org) site.

Then I ran:

```
npm install -g express
```

And voila no problems.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** 2017-06-29: this answer is 6+ years old, but still gets votes/traffic. Instead *(for any new users with problems)* I'd trust both [`NODE_PATH` official doc](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_path_path) and its [corresponding bit about REPL usage](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_addenda_package_manager_tips) before this answer.

Quite similar to this issue, node was not finding my global express install, so a `require('express')` statement would fail.

What fixed this for me, when a global install wasn't being picked up by node was making sure `NODE_PATH` [env. variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) was is set correctly.
On Ubuntu 11.04, with node version 0.5.0-pre, the paths me were:

```
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/lib/node
```

So, to clarify you might want to export the above env. variable, or you can just test the above values out by doing:

```
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/lib/node node ./you_app.js
```

Answer (score 2):

With the release of Express 4.0.0 it looks like you need to do `sudo npm install -g express-generator.`

Comment: Although correct, how is this answer different from the answer already given by Fazi? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23266782/617937

Comment: actually this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a combination of things:

1. From [node.js modules path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465829/node-js-modules-path):

   ```
   echo 'export NODE_PATH="'$(npm root -g)'"' >> ~/.bash_profile && . ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   This sets the file path in bash profile (can be viewed using `nano .bash_profile`
2. Slightly modified from Raynos (above) since I needed `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo npm install express -g
   ```
3. Slightly modified from Fazi (above) since I needed `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo npm install -g express-generator
   ```

**TEST YOUR APPLICATION:**

```
run `DEBUG=myapp:* npm start`
```

Ref: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score 0):

IF you are running windows:

```
export NODE_PATH="C:\Users\IMarek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules"
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have `export`. If you are referring to cygwin or mingw or something like that you should probably make it explicit.