# Load module using node.js require

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm building a *node.js* app using *express* and *jade* frameworks. The app has the standard skeleton, that's how it looks the main directory :

- app.js
- bin
- npm-debug.log
- views
- node_modules
- package.json
- public

The problem occurs when I try to load the *socket.io* module in a *js* file (called lets say *x.js*) within the *public* directory. That's where I've implemented some logic tightly connected to user-action event handling. So in other words when someone clicks on a button 'connect', I'd like to establish connection using *socket.io*. The problem is that when I add this line

*var socket_io = require('socket.io'); in x.js* (*x.js* is located in the /*public* dir)

the whole functionality suddenly stops working, I guess due to the fact that the module is not loaded although the *var socket_io* isn't used anywhere below within the *x.js* file. If I add the line *var socket_io = require('socket.io');* to *app.js* everything works. I looked into this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465829/node-js-modules-path) but with no success. 
Can someone explain why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Just to clarify that I've added 'socket.io' to the package.json file. Also installed *socket.io* both globally and locally using *npm install (-g) socket.io* command.

Comment: the public folder is usually for housing static files and styles. Not really standard practice to have business logic in there.

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks for the explanation! Then where should I implement bussiness logic?

Comment: @e213n because comments cant be structured in any way I have used an answer post to show a sample directory structure that I have used on a project

Comment: Wait. Am I right in assuming that x.js is a client-side (browser) javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To init socket.io you need some crucial things, like the server var that is init in app.js file.
So, if you try to require socket.io out of app.js and you try to init socket.io, then you could have some troubles.
Because socket.io can't be init without the server var in your case.

If you try to require socket.io and not init it. I think you will have not problem. So try to understand the section that is related to Express in the socket.io documentation : http://socket.io/docs/#

Then you can try to use the npm module for express and socket.io : http://express-io.org/

Or you can deal with socket.of() method : http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#

In any event, you should init socket.io with the server var. So, you can make your module to manage socket.io behavior, define some methods, etc. For this purpose, you can passe socket.io in argument to your route files. See here :[Use socket.io inside a express routes file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856190/use-socket-io-inside-a-express-routes-file)
Then, that logic allow you to use socket.io anywhere in your app.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not an attempt to answer the question asked but a further question put to me in the commments.** Ideally I would have answered it in the comments but felt a visual aspect could explain better.
[image: folder structure]
I have a folder structure like this in my app, an MVC type structure. The `controllers/` folder contains the business logic. The `models/` folder contains my models. The routes folder contains `routes/` and the `views/` folder contains my jade templates.