# Installing express in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to install express in my ubuntu using the next command:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

But when I try to use express to create a new app:

```
express new_app_name
```

I get the next error(Is in spanish but it says "express command not found"):

```
express: no se encontró la orden
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23266782/57135

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002448/express-command-not-found/23003386#23003386)

Comment: restart your computer perhaps.?

Comment: duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097826/install-express-with-npm

Answer (score 2):

With the release of Express 4.0.0 or more it looks like you need to do `sudo npm install -g express-generator.` for generate a skeleton for your app